# Why is <Link> tag is not working properly when the content inside not-found.tsx file is being used in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, anchor, next.js13

I have created a `layout.tsx` file where I included a `<Link>` tag that links to the root of my application (`'/'`). The `<Link>` tag works fine when I use it to navigate from an existing page (e.g., `/about`) to return to the home page. But when I am in the 404 page rendered by the content inside `not-found.tsx` file, the `<Link>` tag doesn't work properly.

Here is the link to a video that demonstrates my problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zj-LM6FSpIk&ab_channel=AnuragNepal

I replaced `<Link>` tag with `<a>` tag, and the issue was fixed, but I want to learn why `<Link>` tag didn't work. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is indeed not normal. Don't hesitate to raise an issue on their GitHub page.